# System hangs at startup on the wallpaper with logo

Tags: 11.04, freeze

Hey everyone, I have a little problem with 11.04. I ran the update and after the reboot it takes me on the loading page but that's all I would get. No cursors, no options just the wallpaper and the ubuntu logo.. what can I do? it's been like this for almost 2 hours!

Comment: Do the white dots below the logo remain solid white?

Comment: no at first the turned yellow and everytime I reboot they're yellow already

Comment: Please provide some basic H/W info. Like which graphics card, memory etc bcuz I have seen people struggling with unity with older laptops.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you able to get to the login screen at least, or does the hang occur after login? If it's before, then that part's called Plymouth and you should edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem (freeze on the Ubuntu logo before reaching the login screen) on a Dell Vostro 1520 (using a nvidia graphic card).

I "solved" the problem by switching to the previous Nvidia non free driver (173) instead of the recommanded one.  I hope that a fix will come, because my laptop is extreamly slow with that old driver...

Comment: did you do that from the bios menu? can you please describe me the way you did it? the last thing I want right now is to experiment all by myself and totally destroy my pc :)

Comment: Hello vangelis, 

To do so, first i performed a boot in debug mode and restored the default display parameters.  With this configuration, i've been able to properly log in (but it only works ONCE with the default drivers; if you reboot, you are screwed) and then change my Nvidia driver in the System/Administration/Drivers menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then Ctrl+Alt+F7. If you still don't see the login screen, switch back to the F1 screen and you should be able to login from the command line which will allow you to get some more information about your system.

Comment: the problem remains.. I simply can't do anything. thanks though..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is what I did:

To get your menu bar back, change the login session to Ubuntu Classic; you can see this option in the bottom of the login screen, just when you are about to type your password.

After this, I have installed unity-2d and was able to use Unity. For this, when log back in select Unity-2d instead of Ubuntu Classic.

With Unity, you might need some getting-used-to, but IMHO, it is quite nice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem here sounds like the hang occurs during Plymouth, in which case they won't be able to even try this.